# When I run sql query there is no alert

Tags: ms-access-2016

This code insert the record into the basetable without alert.

```
CurrentDb.Execute _ 
"INSERT INTO basetable(clName,clId,clGender) VALUES('test','123','');"
```

I expected this code should pop alert up because the clGender field set to be "required", but no alert. Could you please tell me where I was wrong.

Comment: How have you validated that the field is required?  When you execute that statement and "there is no alert", what *does* happen?  Is the record inserted?  What value is present for the `clGender` field in that record?

Comment: David, I think setting "required" in the property to yes means it can't be null. the record was not be inserted, which means nothing happens. Also no alert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL " Insert ... "
```

though that may be too much.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you didn't get an alert is because you supplied a value for clGender. In table design view there are two relevant properties: `Required` and `Allow zero length`. Your clGender field has both of these set to true. The `Required` setting means that you can't save the record with this field as `Null` but in your insert statement you haven't specified `Null`, you've specified an empty string, which is allowed by the `Allow zero length` setting.

[EDIT]

Sorry, just realised what's going on. The `Execute` method doesn't give you any feedback directly. However you can use the `RecordsAffected` property to see if it did what you expected.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb()
db.Execute "INSERT INTO basetable(clName,clId,clGender) VALUES('test','123','')"
If db.RecordsAffected = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Insert failed"
End If
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand wha you said but I have specified "Required" as true and "Allow zero lenght" as false. Also I have triedCurrentDb.Execute _ 
`"INSERT INTO basetable(clName,clId,clGender) VALUES(NULL, NULL, NULL);"` but this codes also didn't show alert.

Comment: `RecordsAffected` always returns 0 even if it should not be. I searched this issue but I couldn't find the reason. Programmers said creating db instance of CurrentDb would make `RecordsAffected` work properly. So I expected the codes should work properly because db instance was created. But I got back 0 always.

Comment: Just tested this locally (albeit with Access 2013) and it worked as expected. You say it always returns 0 for `RecordsAffected` - can you confirm that the row is definitely inserted?

Comment: I checked the codes several times and found I got back 0 always. I got back 0 even when a records was inserted. Version is Access 2016. I have no idea what I have to do next.